# TFS2012, VS2008 & Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008, compatibility, scrum

I am currently looking to migrate an existing TFS2008 server to a new VS2012 server.

A major part of the reason behind this is that we want to be able to use the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum template, however I am struggling to determine whether VS2008 is able to manipulate work items created using this template (according to all of the blogs and/or other information I can find, the templates can only be installed to a VS2010 or VS2012 server, but there is nothing clear about Visual Studio clients). I believe that both VS2010 and VS2012 can access an manipulate items based upon these templates.

Note: We HAVE to use VS2008 at the moment as some of the projects are for mobile devices (Windows/CE, Windows Mobile) and, as I am sure you will be aware, these projects are not supported by VS2010 or VS2012).

I am aware of the compatibility GDR's for both VS2008 and VS2010, but again they mention nothing specific about the scrum templates.

So, my question is simple...

Can I access and manipulate (add new work items, update existing items, create a sprint etc) a TFS project that is based upon one of the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum templates on Team Foundation Server 2012 from Team Explorer 2008/Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: I don't have a box to test on, but at a minimum you'd be able to use Web Access to manipulate work items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work Item process templates (e.g. VS Scrum) have **nothing** to do with the version of the client used to connect to TFS, which means that any version of **Visual Studio** (2008, 2010, or 2012) will work with TFS 2012, regardless of the process template (Scrum, Agile MSF or CMMI).

Furthermore, the [**forward compatibility** GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983) provides the team explorer extension (window) that will give VS 2008 the ability to use the new functionality of **TFS** 2012 (e.g. start and end dates for iterations, capacity planning, etc.).

The process template (i.e. Visual Studio Scrum 2.0) is nothing but a set of XML documents detailing which **work item types** you will have, what **fields** they contain, some reports, SharePoint settings, security settings, etc. None of these affect or are affected by the version of Visual Studio.